# How to convert a key to a num lock key using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm reading a key through the KeyDown event, however I'd  like to try to interpret it by seeing what that key would be had num lock be pressed (and on).  Is there a way to do that?

I don't want to programatically set the state of numlock because then I'm sort of at the mercy of the user and have to manage that state.  Also, I have to support any keyboard.

Comment: so you want to for example catch the "8" when its pressed and num lock is not activated?

Comment: This probably isn't going to be easy, I assume you are talking about keyboards where the number keys are integrated into the letter keys, I think this is a manufacturer specific thing, since I don't know of a standard for placement of the numeric keys over the letter ones.

Comment: Some keyboards use num lock to change the meaning of the number pad keys while others without a number pad use it to change a set of keys under the 7-8-9 keys into a defacto number pad.  So, are you sure what you are asking is really what you want?  The whole point of num lock is to allow the user to decide how they want to enter numbers.

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple levels to interpreting keyboard input.

On one level, you get characters - so if the user presses `F`, you'll get a character `f`. If the user presses `Shift+F`, you'll get `F`. Similarly, if the user presses `Num 8` with the numlock on, you'll get `8` (the same as if he pressed alpha-numeric `8`) - but if he presses `Num 8` *without* the numlock on, you'll get nothing.

On another level, you get *keys*. If the user presses `F`, you'll get `Keys.F`. If he presses `Shift+F`, you get `Shift+F`. On the numeric pad, pressing `Num 8` with numlock on gives you `Num 8` (different from alpha-numeric `8`) - but pressing it with numlock off gives you `Up`.

In .NET, those two view of the keyboard are exposed by the `KeyPress` event for characters, and the `KeyDown`/`KeyUp` events for keys.

However, note that *neither* of the two allows you to reinterpret the numeric keypad the way you want! For example, on my keyboard, both pressing the `Up` key and pressing `Num 8` with numlock offs gives you the same key - that's because they *are* logically the same.

More importantly, different keyboards work differently. For example, many laptop keyboards have their numpad on the alpha-numeric keyboard. So if your numlock is off, the same key that used to be `Num 8` is now `I` or something like that. Adapting for weird keyboard layouts is basically the same as writing drivers for each and every keyboard out there - you really don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I made a little test project and overrode the [ProcessCmdKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) to catch any keyboard input. I have a standard keyboard with extra NumPad. When I press a number Key with the NumPad enabled I get NumPadX as `keyData` and when I disable NumLock and press one of the keys again I just get for example `Left` when pressing the 4 key. All possible values can be found in the [Keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) enum
Overriding the `ProcessCmdKeymethod` will basically give you the very first chance to catch any key input in your application. What you won't be able to do is to guess how the keyboard hardware is designed and sends the key press to the OS.